# Search in a directory wav files

Tags: java, file-io

I would like to search in a directory if wav files exist.

How can I do that in java?

Thank you.

Comment: including recursive directory, or just the top level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use this:

```
File dir = new File("/your/dir");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".wav"); 
    }
});
```

Then `files` will contain an array of `File` objects that end with `.wav`. If you just want to know if there are any, check if `files.length > 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class. It can tell you is it a directory and give a list of files. Then you will be able to analyze the extension using `File.getName()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FileFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) with File.list()

```
FileFilter ff = java.io.FileFilter {
    public boolean accept(File f) {
    String name = f.getName().toLowerCase();
    return name.endsWith("wav")
}
dir.list(ff);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion that shows the files deeper in the directory and where you specify what filetype (for re-usability).

```
// This collection will contain all the file names
final Collection<File> fileCollection = new ArrayList<File>(); 

public void addDirectory(File dir, Collection<File> fileCollection, String fileType){

        if (fileType == null){
            fileType = "";
        }

        final File[] children = dir.listFiles();


            if (children != null){
                for(File child : children){

                    if (child.getName().endsWith(fileType)){
                        fileCollection.add(child);
                    }

                    addDirectory(child, fileCollection, fileType);
                }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a filefilter for this specific extension.

```
FileFilter wavFiter = new FileFilter(){ 

@Override
public boolean accept(File pathname) {
  return pathname.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith("wav");
 }
}
```

or for any other

```
class FileExtentionFilter implements FileFilter {

  private final String extenstion;

  FileExtenstionFilter(String extenstion) {
    this.extenstion = extenstion;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean accept(File pathname) {
 return pathname.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith("wav");
 }
}
```

And then use it like this

```
File dir = new File(dirPath);
File[] waves = dir.listFiles(wavFiter);
```

or

```
File dir = new File(dirPath);
File[] waves = dir.listFiles(new FileExtentionFilter("wav"));
```