# displays song from folder to jlist

Tags: java, netbeans, jlist

can anyone here give me a view or idea on how to get the songs from a folder and displays it to jlist? i have no idea on how to start doing this...

thank you guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step one should be defining what song is and where the source folder is, after that everything is easy.

What You need is class [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and of course [Jlist](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html).

Using file object, you will be able to specify a [filter and retrieve proper files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338137/search-in-a-directory-wav-files).

When you will have list of files then you should read this [(How to use Lists)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) tutorial.

EDIT:

What song is ?

The song might be a file that have specific extension usually this is .mp3, .wav.

So when we are trying to find songs in a folder really we are looking for multimedia files.

Comment: thank you sir for your quick response. but i have a question, do i have to specifically define every single song included in a folder? what if there's a lists of songs that i want to display to jlist? thanks...

Comment: What do you mean be lists of songs ? ps. see EDIT.

Comment: ok sir thank you, i understand now. i have to identify a song's extension file... thanks